# How do I install Flash on a Chromebook?

Tags: unity, command-line, flash, chromebook

The instructions are

1. Start up Ubuntu. Use Chromium to download this version of libpepflashplayer.so.
2. Start a terminal and do

   ```
   sudo cp /path/to/libpepflashplayer.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/
   ```
3. Still in terminal, enter:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/chromium-browser/default
   ```

   This should open up gedit with the "default" file. In the default file, there should be a line that says: `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""`
4. In gedit, edit the `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""` line so that it looks like:

   ```
   CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=11.3.31.518 --ppapi-flash-args=enable_hw_video_decode=0,enable_stagevideo_auto=0,enable_trace_to_console=0"
   ```
5. Save and exit gedit.

However when I try to do step two terminal says

```
missing destination file operand after '/path/to/libpepflashplayer.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/'
```

Is this command just trying to move the file to the plugins folder because I cannot seem to do that manually. I am very novice help.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this Chromebook hardware running Ubuntu, or a Chromebook running ChromeOS?  If it is ChromeOS, then this is off topic for Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a chromebook running ubuntu and that is why the installation is complicated.

Comment: Okay.  Are you typing the commands exactly as shown?  The error only looks like it'd occur if you'd added some quotes or escaped the space character.

Comment: Just to be sure you understand this: is the `libpepflashplayer.so` in the `/path/to/` directory? What returns `ls -l /path/to/`? And in what directory is `libpepflashplayer.so`? Maybe `~/Download`?

Comment: It is in downloads folder do I have to move it.

Comment: Of course. I think you should do `mv ~/Download/libpepflashplayer.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/`.

Comment: I just found that the plugins folder is locked and I cannot change the permission settings any ideas how. Thanks for all the input by the way.

Comment: Could you update the question showing the exact commands you're running that result in the error you saw?  As I mentioned in the previous comment, the error message you received makes it look like two arguments to `cp` were quoted and treated as a single one.